# Firefox and android having difficulty with some CSS entries

Tags: php, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

I am having some trouble getting an Android device and Firefox to recognize some CSS entries.  I believe the issue is related to the fact I'm combining class and id attributes.

Here is the CSS:

```
ul#sub-notification {z-index:3;list-style:none;font-weight:bold;}
#sub-notification li{display:block;text-align:center;width:280px;padding:7px;background:#fff;border-left:1px #c0c0c0 solid;border-bottom:1px #c0c0c0 solid;border-top:1px #c0c0c0 solid;}
#sub-notification li a {color:#111;font-size:.9em;}
#sub-notification li:hover {background:#383838;}
#sub-notification li:hover  a {color:#33FF66;}
ul#sub-notification.click{display:block;position:absolute;right:0px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;max-height:500px;}
ul#sub-notification.unclick{display:none;}
```

And here is the source for the actual notification area as seen by Firefox:

```
<!-- ### START notification ### -->
<div id="notification">
     <a href="#" title="notification" id='notification-link' class="unread">1    NEW Notification(s)</a>

      <ul id='sub-notification' class='unclick'>
           <li><a href="#" title="#">To ID: 9<br/>From ID: 3<br/>Read: 0<br/>Type: <em>0</em><br/>Text: <em>Test notification</em><br/></a>
        </li>
     </ul>                  
</div>
<!-- ### END notification ### -->
```

If anyone has suggestions or an idea of what is occuring that would be great.  IE, IE compatibility Mode, Chrome, Safari and Opera all seem to be alright.

Comment: Which styles are not being applied? Can you also clarify which browser(s) the issue presents itself in? From your question, you could mean Firefox for Android or Android browser and Firefox.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity...the three that are not getting applied are: `ul#sub-notification {z-index:3;list-style:none;font-weight:bold;}
ul#sub-notification.click{display:block;position:absolute;right:0px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;max-height:500px;}
ul#sub-notification.unclick{display:none;} `  and I was seeing this in a Chrome Android browser as well as Firefox 36.0.3

Comment: I put it in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/dcp2cx0f/), but what are the differences between Firefox, Chrome and IE supposed to be?

Comment: They should all be showing that way (1 NEW Notification(s)) and be at the very right of the screen with no list style but in FF 36 I was seeing the bullet and it was on the left so list-style:none and right:0px were clearly being ignored.  I don't  think it was applying any of the ul#sub-notification styles